# Does the left adjoint of the homotopy coherent nerve have a name?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

The simplicial nerve $N: \operatorname{Sset-Cat} \to \operatorname{Sset}$ has the left adjoint $\mathfrak{C}: \operatorname{Sset} \to \operatorname{Sset-Cat}.$ Wherever I see it, it is always referred by its symbol (and even that is not consistent: [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+coherent+nerve#for_the_homotopy_coherent_nerve) it is called "$S$"). That's awkward and weird. Is there a (n at least proposed) name for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard name for this functor.

One could call it the *rigidification functor*, since rigidification (or strictification) is a recognized name for this type of constructions.

However, such a name can refer to any of the several weakly equivalent models for this functor, see, for example, [Rigidification of quasi-categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0814) by Dugger and Spivak.

Answer (score 1):

Emily Riehl calls it (e.g. in [Homotopy coherent structures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.07404.pdf)), *homotopy coherent realization*, due to "formal similarity" with the realization functor $\operatorname{Top} \to  \operatorname{Sset}.$

Images of standard simplices are called *homotopy coherent simplices*. There is a related functor $\mathfrak{C}: \operatorname{Cat} \to \operatorname{Sset-Cat}$ which makes a "homotopy coherent" indexing category out of an ordinary one (enabling one to define a *homotopy coherent diagram* in the evident way), which is called the *free resolution* functor. A homotopy coherent simplex can be seen as a free resolution of the category $\mathfrak{n}$, or as the homotopy coherent realization of of the standard simplex $\Delta^n$.

The formal similarity mentioned above seems to be that homotopy coherent diagram of a simplicial set is glued from homotopy coherent simplices in the same way the realization of a simplicial set is glued from standard simplices - as a colimit over the category of elements of this simplicial set.